# Do readers think of the word "ejaculate" beyond its common sexual meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, connotation, poetry

I am an editor, and a poet whom I work with has included the expression "I ejaculated little prayers" in one of his stanzas, which we all know has the dictionary meaning of "intensely calling out." Since the spiritual act of praying is completely at odds with the sexual act, I know the poet would be absolutely horrified should the reading public immediately think only or primarily of ejaculate's sexual meaning.

My question is will people in general only think of the sexual connotation?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not everybody, but for me, yes, I immediately thought of the sexual connotation and assumed that the prayers were uttered in a state of excitement or extasy. That is not necessarily bad of course.

Comment: Or [Sherlock Holmes](http://qi.com/infocloud/sherlock-holmes) (well, John Watson anyway).

Comment: "I'm coming!" Tom ejaculated.

Comment: Have you asked the poet to clarify his meaning?

Comment: It's utterly weird that so many people are so illiterate they don't realise ejaculate just means "blurt something out" in speech.

Answer (score 4):

Stephen Fry on QI (TV show):

> Watson ‘ejaculates’ twice as often as Sherlock Holmes in Conan Doyle’s stories. There are
>   23 ejaculations in total, with 11 belonging to Watson. On one occasion, Holmes refers to
>   Watson’s ‘ejaculations of wonder’ being invaluable; on another, Watson ejaculates
>   ‘from his very heart’ in the direction of his fiancee. Holmes is only responsible for
>   six ejaculations, although it is not clear which of the two men ejaculate in the passage
>   below: ‘So he sat as I dropped off to sleep, and so he sat when a sudden ejaculation
>   caused me to wake up, and I found the summer sun shining into the apartment. The pipe
>   was still between his lips...’ A chap called Phelps ejaculated three times during the
>   story of ‘The Naval Treaty.’ The only other ejaculator is Mrs. St. Clair’s husband, who
>   ejaculates at her from a second-floor window in the story ‘The Man with the Twisted Lip’.

You really can't use the word these days without causing confusion so better to use an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

An ejaculation in the non-sexual sense is basically an exclamation. In the right context, such as calling out in pain or surprise, this connotation might be clear, but it doesn't seem quite right even by this definition in relation to prayer.

A Google books search for "[ejaculate](https://www.google.com/#q=ejaculate&start=0&tbm=bks)" and its conjugated forms shows an overwhelming number of hits for its use in the sexual sense.

Unless the poet actually means exclamation AND is going for a double meaning, I think the word is best avoided.

Comment: While I am aware of the second usage of "ejaculated/ejaculation", I concur with nxx that it is best avoided if you are seeking to specifically communicate the idea of an excited utterance. I always default to the sexual meaning because of the relatively infrequent usage of the exclamatory definition in most conversation and literature.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the case of ejaculated prayers it would come across as being a "religio-sexual" juxtaposition.  I assume that you know the poet's intent and he does not wish that sort of thing(?).  Because, otherwise it almost sounds like a case of religious ecstasy …

In terms of non-sexual usage it is always an exclamation:

> "What the hell is that?", John ejaculated.

It is definitely a word that has diminished in non-sexual usage over the years. (An NGRAM would prove difficult to interpret here since I can't seem to get it to remove the sexual connotation …)

In my opinion, it would be best to avoid the word unless making a deliberate reference to religious ecstasy.

Answer (score 1):

Today "to ejaculate" is in my view always associated with its sexual meaning. And I think, to use it today in the sense of to utter is anachronistic. Today it is understood sexually and any other use would raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 0):

I can actually give you a direct quote from a book I own, called *The Va Dinci Cod*, a parody of the eponymous Dan Brown novel / film. It comes in the form of a footnote:

```
*[Publishers' note: we wish to inform the public that we urged the author,
Don Brine, to remove the phrase 'ejaculated Teabag' from his manuscript and
replace it with 'said the Baronet in a wholesome manner entirely free
from surreally obscene overtones'.]
```

I think it's fair to say that, though it may once have been used to refer to a sudden interjection in the middle of a conversation, I note that [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ejaculate) (among others such as [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ejaculated), [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ejaculate) and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ejaculate)) insists on putting the sexual connotation as the primary definition, even if they play host to both definitions as valid.

Wikipedia also redirects to the page on medical ejaculation and has a specifically-named page for the grammatical interjection.

...I should probably clear my internet history now.