# “An exclamation” or “An ejaculation” ? Are these words synonymous?

Tags: meaning, differences

Exclamations and ejaculations are usually expressions of surprise or anxiety, something said quickly and suddenly.  Grammatically they are always interjections and may seem to be the same kind of utterance.   Are they ?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/161474

Comment: @tchrist I checked that one before posting my question.

Comment: As OxfordDictionaries says of [**ejactulate:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ejaculate) **DATED** *- to say something quickly and suddenly*. That's because the more common sense today is *(Of a man or male animal) eject semen from the body at the moment of sexual climax*, which I think is General Reference.

Comment: FumbleFingers I've read the two words are not exactly synonimous. I'm waiting for someone to come up with the difference or tell me there is none at all.

Comment: @ Luis: By far the biggest difference is that *ejaculate = exclaim* is a ***dated*** usage, for the reason given. It's a complete waste of time looking for any more subtle distinction, given how big that one is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand I should delete the question then ?

Comment: This question has a very suggestive interjection upon my thoughts.

Comment: @Luis No, don't delete the question. Leave it up for posterity's sake.

Comment: What @Stephen said. Besides which I don't think you *can* delete your question once it has answers (and it can be very annoying if someone deletes their question *while* someone else is answering it).

Answer (score 3):

A wikipedia search kind of clears the air on the difference. Ejaculate is clearly a word which is used today in an entirely unrelated context- albeit similar (who really expects ejaculations!)
 Both ejaculate and exclaim indicate surprise, but vary in the degree of expression. For instance, an "ooh" or an "aah" is an ejaculation.
Exclamations on the other hand are of two kinds- clausal containing a subject+verb, eg. the very colloquial "God damn it!" and phrasal- consisting of phrases.

Answer (score -1):

They are [**synonyms**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ejaculation?ref=dictionary&word=exclamation#) and  though ejaculation is defined as "a sudden discharging of a fluid from a duct", the connotation is ejection from the urethra.  Unlike Brazil, Americans tend to use a [**dysphemism**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dysphemism) with sexual connotations.

Comment: Just in case you missed it, Brazil isn't an English Speaking Country.

Comment: @Luis  ...............É mesmo?

Comment: If you speak Portuguese, then you know we have our euphemisms and dysphemisms, with or without sexual connotations.